# How to delete part of media recorder?

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I'm using get user media & media recorder api to record users video.

I would like to create a button to clear the last part of the recorded stream since he paused the recording.

I didn't find anyway to do that!
If someones has an idea it would be really helpful !!

**PS: if you want an example try TikTok delete option when you pose the recording**

Answer (score 0):

[`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) delivers its coded output to the [`ondataavailable` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) you provide. Unfortunately that data is delivered to your event handler as [`Blob` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

You can extract the Blob data into an ArrayBuffer with a variety of methods. But then you'll have to cope with the [ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebml) / [matroska](https://www.matroska.org/) / [webm](https://www.webmproject.org/) boxing format, not to mention the difference between key frames and delta frames in the video stream, and similar sample-buffer boundary issues in the audio stream(s).

What you want to do is going to be difficult-to-impossible in a pure HTML5 / Javascript implementation.

Comment: This looks preaty hard. Isn't there another way to do that ??